# CSS vertical center

Tags: html, css

Consider the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/q5t26m0b/

I'd like to get the `span` that contains "BP" to center vertically with the `colorName` `span`s, no matter how many `colorName`s there are.

If possible, I'd also like the "BP" to be overlapped if any `colorName`s are long enough to get over there.

Feel free to suggest whatever changes are necessary to the HTML or CSS.

```
<div class="wide-field">
<div class="info-area" id="colorlist-textarea">
<div class='artboard-colors'>
<span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
<span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
<span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
<span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
<span class='artboard-id'>BP</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

.wide-field {
display: inline-block;
width: 98%;
}

.info-area {
border: 1px solid black;
font-size: 14px;
width: 100%;
resize: none;
overflow: auto;
padding: 5px;
}

#colorlist-textarea {
height: 15em;
}

.artboard-colors
{
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
border: 1px dashed darkgreen;
padding: 1px;
margin: 1px;
}

.colorName
{
display: inline-block; 
vertical-align:middle;
border:solid black 1px; 
width: 75%; 
}

.artboard-id
{
float: right;
text-align: right;
display: inline-block; 
vertical-align:middle;
width: 20%; 
border: 1px solid #d1c7ac; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want overlap then you'll need to use positioning.

Using absolute positioning on the BP element allows us to fix its location at 50% of the height of the parent div (adjusted by a transform) and allow it to sit on top of the color bars.

*Note: I have removed the 75% width of the bars as this would have meant that they would never reach the BP element.*

Also, I switched the "colorname" spans from `inline-block` to plain old `block`.

```css
.wide-field {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 98%;
}
.info-area {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
#colorlist-textarea {
  height: 15em;
}
.artboard-colors {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed darkgreen;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
.colorName {
  display: block;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
.artboard-id {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #d1c7ac;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide-field">
  <div class="info-area" id="colorlist-textarea">
    <div class='artboard-colors'>
      <span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
      <span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
      <span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
      <span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
      <span class='artboard-id'>BP</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to get the span that contains "BP" to center vertically with the colorName spans, no matter how many colorNames there are.

This code should solve this issue. It's a modified version of [this](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) that uses absolute positioning instead of relative, so it's flexible no matter how many `<span class='colorName'>`s there are.

```css
.wide-field {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 98%;
}

.info-area {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

#colorlist-textarea {
  outline: 1px dashed red;
  position: relative;
}

.artboard-colors {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed darkgreen;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
}

.colorName {
  display: block; 
  border:solid black 1px; 
  width: 75%; 
}

.artboard-id { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 20%; 
  border: 1px solid #d1c7ac;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wide-field">
  <div class="info-area" id="colorlist-textarea">
    <div class='artboard-colors'> 
      <span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
      <span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
      <span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
      <span class='colorName'>PANTONE Bleck</span>
    </div>
    <span class='artboard-id'>BP</span>
  </div>
</div>
```